# Overriding default ASP.Net MVC scaffolding HTML

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

Each time I use Visual Studio to generate a display-template using scaffolding I get something like this:

```
<fieldset>
    ...
    <div class="display-label">Property</div>
    <div class="display-field">@Model.Property</div>
    ...
</fieldset>
```

Is there any way to change this template so that it use a HTML definition list instead?

```
<dl>
    ...
    <dt>Property</dt>
        <dd>@Model.Property</dd>
    ...
</dl>
```

I know you could use DisplayTemplates, but I want the generated code to be default in all my projects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the following post: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2009/01/27/asp-net-mvc-1-0-release-candidate-now-available.aspx. It describes customizing the templates. While it was written about Mvc 1 everything still applies

Comment: ok thanks, that seems to be it. However, I cannot locate the "ItemTemplates" folder inside my Visual Studio installation. Any ideas why? I use Visual Studio 2010 Pro...

Comment: Thad located under Common7\IDE. In your VS installation directory (also file search is your friend :)

Comment: I know where they're supposed to be, but they are not there :S Search returns no results for either the folder name or an existing template, like "create.tt".

Comment: Should be under a path like this: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\ItemTemplates\CSharp\Web\MVC 3\CodeTemplates\AddView\CSHTML (in MVC 3). If they're not there you might want to try reinstalling the MVC tooling.

Answer (score 2):

If you are having trouble finding the item templates you can add them to your project with Nuget: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/joecar/archive/2011/01/06/add-the-asp-net-mvc-3-code-templates-to-your-application-with-nuget.aspx

Comment: Yep, that's what I had to do. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this through T4 templates.  Take a look at the explanation in this thread. [How do I create my own Scaffold Template in ASP.NET MVC 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4692311/how-do-i-create-my-own-scaffold-template-in-asp-net-mvc-3)