# In MVC Scaffolding, how do you make a custom scaffolder global?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, scaffolding

MVC Scaffolding is definitely cool. I created a custom scaffolder and custom template to create a Javascript test using YUI-Test.

What do I do to make this global -- available in any Visual Studio solution?

Many thanks.

Comment: Check this out.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4692311/how-do-i-create-my-own-scaffold-template-in-asp-net-mvc-3

Comment: That post shows how to reuse a custom template, but how do I reuse a custom scaffolder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Steven Sanderson has the answer.

http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2011/04/07/mvcscaffolding-creating-custom-scaffolders/