# How to create a Text area in default layout

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, html

Whenever u create a View for new create thread or edit thread what u get is a text box. I need a Text area to be displayed for writing how should i go about it.

Answer (score 2):

`@Html.TextArea` or `@Html.TextAreaFor`

Same as the other HTML helpers.

You can also add the following annotation to your model

```
[DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
```

When you call `EditorFor` you'll get a textarea rather than a textbox.

If you're talking about actually changing the scaffolding template, you need to [create your own  template.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4692311/how-do-i-create-my-own-scaffold-template-in-asp-net-mvc-3)