# Generating scaffolding template recursively for MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Consider following compostion relation between `Child` & `Root` classes-

```
public class Child
{
    public string ChildProperty { get; set; }
}
public class Root
{
    public Child child { get; set; }
    public string RootProperty { get; set; }
}
```

Creating strongly typed view for `Root` class, **does not include** `child` property.

```
<fieldset>
    <legend>Root</legend>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.RootProperty)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.RootProperty)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.RootProperty)
    </div>

    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Save" />
    </p>
</fieldset>
```

How do I generate scaffolding template to include child properties as well?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Generally you would need to create your own T4 templates that do just that:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/16072432/176877

But, I'm not certain you could actually loop through those child models; I'm fairly certain you would need to take things a step farther and actually generate a Custom Scaffold with your own PowerShell script that loops through those models and calls a new set of templates you create.

http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2011/04/07/mvcscaffolding-creating-custom-scaffolders/

In other words, you have a lot of work ahead of you if you want to do this.