# Can we use tt templates instead of T4 templates in Custom Scaffolding

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-mvc-4

Can we use tt templates instead of T4 templates in Custom Scaffolding for generating Controllers & views.

Or do we have a tool for converting tt templates to t4 templates ?

Please suggest.

Thanks & Regards
Christena

Answer (score 1):

The tt templates are t4 templates, just the file extension is tt.

See the location of the files:
[How do I create my own Scaffold Template in ASP.NET MVC 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4692311/how-do-i-create-my-own-scaffold-template-in-asp-net-mvc-3)