# ASP.Net MVC 4 scaffolding complex types

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc-4, scaffolding

I have a very complex model. I want to create Create, edit, list, etc. forms for it. The class contains many objects from other classes. For example in the "create" form, I want a form which is able to get the data for all the classes and fill the necessary tables. How can I achieve that? A sample of my class would be something like this:

```
public class BuildingPermit
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public Permit PermitInfo { get; set; }

    public DateTime RegisteredDate { get; set; }

    public int RealStateID { get; set; }

    public virtual Person Owner{ get; set; }
}
```

When I use the "Scaffolding", the classes like `Person` or `Permit` above are getting ignored and I get fields for system types only.

Comment: Your custom classes must also eventually resolve to system types.  I haven't used scaffolding in awhile, but it's reasonable to assume that each custom class has to generate its own scaffolding.

Comment: Of course they resolve in system types. Every class ultimately resolves to system types. I assume you're right, but how can I gather them all in one form? That's my concern.

Comment: Take a look at this related post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4692311/how-do-i-create-my-own-scaffold-template-in-asp-net-mvc-3