# How can I create my own Scaffolding on Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: visual-studio-2017, repository, asp.net-mvc-scaffolding

I'm using a scaffolding in visual studio 2017 now, but I want to set up my own scaffolding template and controller and I want to replace the previous one

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Play around with all MVC templates at C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\ItemTemplates\CSharp\Web\MVC\1033

Refer: [How do I create my own Scaffold Template in ASP.NET MVC 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4692311/how-do-i-create-my-own-scaffold-template-in-asp-net-mvc-3#4692521)